# event bubbling in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure how should I resolve the following event bubbling situation in jQuery.

I have a link inside a list element (li), which has an on click event. I would like to put an action on li element, which would call link event (click) and call action on li if user clicks a link inside the list element (I always want to trigger click event on li when li or anything inside is clicked).

How should I accomplish this?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<li>
   <img src="images/img.png" />
   <a href="/remote/path" data-remote="true">Link</a>
</li>
```

and jQuery code (which obviosly won't work):

```
$("li a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventBubble = true;
});

$("li").click(function() {
  $el = $(this).find('a');
  $el.click();
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

What is the most elegant solution to this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: It's not really clear what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you right, you should use jQuery [.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) instead of implementing this by yourself.

> **event.stopPropagation()**
>
> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

And the implementation:

```
$("li a").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: The problem is, that I still get "too much recursion" error, which I thought its because of event bubbling when I click the element. Do you have any idea why is that happening?

Comment: I think the issue is that it will loop calling the functions.. please see the link

Comment: @Aljaz It's still not clear enough to me what you're trying to do. You want the page to move to the href or  not?

Comment: Also your code isn't using what I've written in the answer at all... Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/UWn4e/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**`event.stopPropagation()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) or [**`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)

```
$("li a").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Usually I used to do this using `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()`

Better go with **return false;**, check out the reason [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/1671639)

> `e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occuring,
>   `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up and
>   **`return false`** will do both.

---

From you fidde, it is not necessary to have 2 functions for `li` and `a`.

You already have like this

```
<ul id="some_list">
    <li> <a href="/remote-path" data-remote="true">Some link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here it seems **`li` == `a`**, so why you want to 2 different function.

Try like this and check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UWn4e/2/) to know the reason.

```
<ul id="some_list">
    <li>
        <a href="/remote-path" data-remote="true">Some link</a>Text apart from a
    </li>
</ul>
```